# Python issubset on a set of sets

Tags: python, set

I have a set of sets:

```
>>> x = set()
>>> x.add(frozenset({1}))
>>> x.add(frozenset({2}))
>>> x.add(frozenset({3}))
>>> x
{frozenset({2}), frozenset({3}), frozenset({1})}
```

I have a candidate set:

```
>>> y = frozenset({2})
>>> y
frozenset({2})
```

I want to know if my candidate set is in my set of sets:

```
>>> y.issubset(x)
False
>>>
```

Why does this return False? How should I determine if my candidate set is in my set of sets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x = set()
x.add(frozenset({1}))
x.add(frozenset({2}))
x.add(frozenset({3}))
print(x)

y = frozenset({2})
print(y in x) # check if candidate set is in set of sets
```

This should return True

Comment: Wow! An answer in less time than it took to walk the dog around the block! Thank you, kind sir (or madam, as the case may be).

Answer (score 0):

You confused the concept of subset and element.

In your case, `y` is an element of `x`, not a subset of `x`. Therefore you should check by `y in x` (check if `y` is an element of `x`) not `y.issubset(x)` (check if every element of `y` is also an element of `x`).

Answer (score 0):

Your variables are slightly different:

- `x := {{1}, {2}, {3}}`, and
- `y := {2}`.

Note that 2 isn't in x, so y ins't a subset of x. I think you meant:

```
>>> x = set()
>>> x.add(frozenset({1}))
>>> x.add(frozenset({2}))
>>> x.add(frozenset({3}))
>>> x
{frozenset({2}), frozenset({3}), frozenset({1})}
>>>
>>> {frozenset({2}), frozenset({3}), frozenset({1})}
{frozenset({2}), frozenset({3}), frozenset({1})}
>>>
>>> y = {frozenset({2})}
>>> y.issubset(x)
True
>>>
>>> y = set()
>>> y.add(frozenset({2}))
>>> y.issubset(x)
True
>>> y <= x
True
```